# MacOSX11 sdk building syntax error

Tags: macos, xcode, homebrew, development

I'm trying to build GIMP from source on MacOSX and I'm getting some syntax erros at some qos.h files:

```
  GISCAN   Gimp-3.0.gir
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.3.sdk/usr/include/sys/qos.h:130: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting identifier or typedef-name or '{' in '# 130 "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/qos.h" 3 4' at ':'
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.3.sdk/usr/include/pthread/qos.h:84: syntax error, unexpected identifier in '  qos_class_t __qos_class, int __relative_priority);' at 'qos_class_t'
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.3.sdk/usr/include/pthread/qos.h:115: syntax error, unexpected identifier in '  qos_class_t * _Nullable restrict __qos_class,' at 'qos_class_t'
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.3.sdk/usr/include/pthread/qos.h:116: syntax error, unexpected BASIC_TYPE, expecting identifier or '(' or '*' in '  int * _Nullable restrict __relative_priority);' at 'int'
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.3.sdk/usr/include/pthread/qos.h:116: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting ',' or ';' in '  int * _Nullable restrict __relative_priority);' at ')'
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.3.sdk/usr/include/pthread/qos.h:155: syntax error, unexpected identifier, expecting ')' or ',' in 'pthread_set_qos_class_self_np(qos_class_t __qos_class,' at '__qos_class'
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.3.sdk/usr/include/pthread/qos.h:187: syntax error, unexpected identifier in '  qos_class_t * _Nullable restrict __qos_class,' at 'qos_class_t'
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.3.sdk/usr/include/pthread/qos.h:188: syntax error, unexpected BASIC_TYPE, expecting identifier or '(' or '*' in '  int * _Nullable restrict __relative_priority);' at 'int'
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.3.sdk/usr/include/pthread/qos.h:188: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting ',' or ';' in '  int * _Nullable restrict __relative_priority);' at ')'
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.3.sdk/usr/include/pthread/qos.h:266: syntax error, unexpected identifier in '  qos_class_t __qos_class, int __relative_priority);' at 'qos_class_t'
```

I'm also getting gegl symbol error just below on build log:

```
Gimp-3.0.gir:3977.59-3977.59: error: The symbol `Gegl' could not be found
Gimp-3.0.gir:3983.83-3983.83: error: The symbol `Gegl' could not be found
Gimp-3.0.gir:3989.59-3989.59: error: The symbol `Gegl' could not be found
```

the variables XDG_DATA_DIRS and XDG_DATA_HOME are set to `/usr/local/share`

Are this errors related ? Anyone know how to fix it ?

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is on topic here or should be on Stack Exchange, but you could avoid reinventing the wheel, there's a dedicated Mac port maintained at  https://www.partha.com/ though they only do release versions.

Comment: I encounter the same problem, have you solved it?

Comment: It seems that currently gimp's build is based on lower version of macosx sdk